# React - renderToString how to apply styles to a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, object, react-redux

I am using react-html-parser and renderToString. The problem is that I cannot apply the styles to the string, because the renderTostring styles and classes renders the string. Here is an example https://ibb.co/8mfRWGm. How to solve this problem?

**JavaScript_Lessons_Objects.js**

```
{
    titleName: "Creating Your First JavaScript",
    heading: 'Ready. Set. JavaScript!',
    iconName: faDotCircle,
    description: [
        `
        <h2 class="title_description">Let’s start</h2>
        With the basics and add some JavaScript to a webpage.
        document, and needs to be enclosed by
        ${ReactDOMServer.renderToString("<script class'scriptClass' style='color: red'> and </script>")}
        `
    ],
},
```

**Lessons.jsx**

```
ReactHtmlParser(this.props.lesson[this.state.indexDescription]["description"])
```

Comment: Can you please add punctuation to your question?

Comment: frankly, I tried it but unfortunately it didn't work out I ask questions using google translate and if I added punctuation on my question my translation would break

Comment: script tag is reserved tag to execute javascript. Try using different html tag like `div`